# Authenticity of host can't be established; can I add a key or something?

Tags: ssh, authentication

So I get this message sometimes when SSHing to my home machine from my work machine:

```
The authenticity of host '172.20.60.172 (172.20.60.172)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:45:fb:04:f1:96:66:5a:6a:d8:e7:4c:f2:71:8c:ae.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '172.20.60.172' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

I understand what the message means and the reason for it; I **DO NOT** want to disable it.  My home machine's IP address changes frequently for reasons beyond my control (there is no way to give it a static IP, so don't ask).

Is there some key or fingerprint or something I can add to my local SSH config so that no matter what IP address I'm connecting to, if it sees that fingerprint (which never changes), it says "Ah, I know that fingerprint" and is okay with it? Or am I simply doomed to the immeasurable inconvenience of having to type "yes" once in a while?

Comment: Can you connect using a [dynamic dns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: If he can, he can just make a config entry for that DNS name and disable `CheckHostIP`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I figured as much, I just didn't know the steps to set that up (that's why I did not post an answer) but I knew someone else would pick up where i left off :)

Comment: just some logic clearing, if the key is shown on screen, the "yes" have to be prompt, if no "yes" press, then the key will not be shown. And you are asking to show the key, on some time <-- need to define when, but no need to press the "yes" button ?

Comment: @Kenster Thanks for clarifying, i think i saw the right problem now.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Your comment more or less answers my question, though not in the way I expected. ;) Since the point of the warning is to let you know that the host key is coming from a different IP address than it originally was, in the case where the IP has changed, you should always receive a warning.  CheckHostIp turns that off, but I don't want to turn that off.

That said, the solution would seem to be to add the host's IP and host key to known_hosts whenever it changes; I could probably configure this to happen automatically, but it's also probably not worth the effort. :)